# (Julia 1.0) Accessing Module Variables as Local?

Tags: julia

I have a module containing a number of mathematical and physical constants. As it stands, I am able to access the variables through namespacing:

## constants.jl

```
module Constant
export c

const c = 299792458  # m/s

end
```

## working_example.jl

```
include("constants.jl")

println(Constant.c) # 299792458
```

However, I am looking to access the module variables as local variables e.g. `E=m*c^2`;

## ideal.jl

```
include("constants.jl")

"""
something here
"""

println(c) # 299792458
```

I assume that in order to achieve this I need to implement either `using` or `import`, however in both scenarios I get error

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package Constant not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Constant")` to install the Constant package.
```

Adding this to the `ideal.jl` code does not solve the problem:

## not_working_example.jl

```
include("constants.jl")
import Pkg
Pkg.add("Constant")
import Constant

println(c)
```

which fails with error

```
ERROR: LoadError: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * Constant (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
```

How do I go about resolving this?

P.S. I am aware that the current naming convention is not ideal - this is not set in stone and may change at a later date. I am using Julia v1.0.2:

```
$ julia -v
julia version 1.0.2
```

Comment: You also might have a look at  [https://github.com/ajkeller34/Unitful.jl](Unitful) for adding strongly typed units to your constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried

```
include("constants.jl")
using .Constant

println(c)
```

see the [document](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/)

Comment: That resolved it, many thanks! Rather embarrassingly, I had overlooked the relative path section of the documentation.